# filtering the data which is of iretable[map[string,string ]] type

Tags: scala

I am writing the code in **Scala** language, and have a data which is of `Iterable[Map[String, String]]` type and I wanted to short it as:

```
val data = List(  
  Map("name1" -> "kislay", "name2" -> "kumar"), 
  Map("name1" -> "rupesh", "name2" -> "rupesh")
)
```

I wanted the result to be in this format :

```
val result = List(
  Map("name1" -> "kislay", "name2" -> "kumar"), 
  Map("name1" -> "rupesh", "name2" -> "")
)
```

ie. when ever the name1 and name2 is equal it should leave the name2 place empty or put "N/A" at that place.

Comment: Do you mean `iterable` instead of `iretable` ?

Comment: And does your `Map` will ALWAYS have only 2 key (name1 and name2) or you can have more key / value?

Comment: Complementing @MickaelLeger comment, does both keys will always exist?, if not what should happen if any _(or both)_ of the are missing? - Also, what have you tried so far? You may take a look to [**"how to ask"**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve this and future questions. Specially you should provide some [**"research effort"**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Comment: I kinda like `iretable`. Has a certain je ne sais quoi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, we have a `Map` and we want to change some of the values depending on the relationship of the keys. In other words...

```
Map("xyz" -> "ss1", "abc" -> "ss1")  //change this
Map("xyz" -> "N/A", "abc" -> "ss1")  //to this
```

...because `"ss1"` is a duplicate value and, since `"abc"` comes before `"xyz"` (lexical order), we'll modify the `"xyz"` key/value pair, but leave the `"abc"` key/value unchanged.

Let's make our data set a little more interesting.

```
val nameMap = Map("name1" -> "rupesh"   //keep
                 ,"name2" -> "rupesh"   //drop
                 ,"name3" -> "bo"       //keep
                 ,"name4" -> "am"       //keep
                 ,"name5" -> "bo"       //drop
                 ,"name6" -> "rupesh")  //drop
```

And we're also going to need an `Map` inverter.

```
implicit class MapInverterA[K,V](m :Map[K,V]) {
  def invert :Map[V,Set[K]] =               /*from Map[K,V] to Map[V,Set[K]]*/
    m.foldLeft(Map.empty[V, Set[K]]) {
      case (acc,(k, v)) => acc + (v -> (acc.getOrElse(v,Set()) + k))
    }
}
```

Now we can create an inverted `nameMap`, keeping only the keys we want.

```
val inm = nameMap.invert           //invert the Map
                 .mapValues(_.min) //keep just the 1st keys
```

And use that to make the desired mods.

```
nameMap.map{case (k,v) =>
    if (k == inm(v)) k -> v      //unchanged
    else             k -> "N/A"  //duplicate name
}
//res0: Map(name3 -> bo, name6 -> N/A, name2 -> N/A, name4 -> am, name1 -> rupesh, name5 -> N/A)
```

The only thing left is to apply this to your irritable iterable.

```
val result = data.map{m =>
  val inv = m.invert.mapValues(_.min)
  m.map{case (k,v) => if (k == inv(v)) k->v else k->"N/A"}
}
```